# Why can't I use .Any()?

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql

Right off the bat I'm very new to LINQ to SQL (and C# in general) and haven't successfully implemented .Any() before. I'm using .Net 4.0 with Visual Studio 2010.

I've added a new LINQ to SQL data set to my project and I'm trying to do the following:

```
var db = new HealthIndicatorsDataContext();

var d = DateTime.Today;

if(db.HealthIndicators.FirstOrDefault(h => h.LogDate == d).Any())
 // do something
```

Unfortunately I'm receiving `Cannot Resolve Sysmbol 'Any'` and .Any() is highlighted in red. I've read that I needed to reference System.Core.dll in my project, I've added this but I'm still having no luck. What am I missing?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
if(db.HealthIndicators.FirstOrDefault(h => h.LogDate == d).Any())
```

`FirstOrDefault()` returns a *single* item and not an `IQueryable` or `IEnumerable` - `Any()` is only defined on those. What you probably meant to write is:

```
if(db.HealthIndicators.FirstOrDefault(h => h.LogDate == d) != null))
```

or (better):

```
if(db.HealthIndicators.Any(h => h.LogDate == d)))
```

Answer (score 6):

FirstOrDefault() does not return a collection so Any() does not make sense.  You can replace FirstOrDefault() with .Any() if you only need to know if at least one exists.

```
if(db.HealthIndicators.Any(h => h.LogDate == d))
// do something
```